# How to call a different render after a form submission

Tags: python, flask

I'm diving into Flask for the first time and I'm having some trouble getting something work.

I currently have a  template for when my tab `values` is empty, it contains a form that when submitted should call a specific function using the parameters of the form and return another template. Each call of the form should in, fact call the `index.html` template with different values.

Relevant parts of code are as follows:

`main.py`

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def main():

    global maxDepth, numberOfRelated

    if not values:
        return render_template('initial.html')

    if request.method=='POST':
        url = request.form['url']
        maxDepth = request.form['depth']
        numberOfRelated = request.form['numberOfRelated']

        values = crawling(url,maxDepth,numberOfRelated)

        return render_template('index.html',var=values)
```

The form part of `initial.html` and `index.html` are actually the same

```
<form class="form-inline" action="/" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input  name='url' type="text" class="form-control"/>
              </div>             
               <div class="form-group minorForm">
                <input  name='numberOfRelated' type="text" class="form-control" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group minorForm">
                  <input  name='depth' type="text" class="form-control" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group navbar-right">
                <button class="btn btn-success minorForm generate" type="submit"> Generate</button>
              </div> 
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `main` method, unless values is global, it won't be defined for `if not values`.

As to your question, add another `render_template` call just after the conditional for if the form was submitted:

```
if request.method=='POST':
    url = request.form['url']
    maxDepth = request.form['depth']
    numberOfRelated = request.form['numberOfRelated']
    values = crawling(url,maxDepth,numberOfRelated)
    return render_template('index.html',var=values) # 1
return render_template('index.html',var=values) # 2
```

If the form is submitted, the conditional will be true and the template will be rendered at comment `#1`. If the user is navigating to the page normally, the conditional will be false and the line with comment `#2` will be called.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I had another bug because of the type of  `request.form['depth']` but a cast solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about the question, but you should always redirect after a POST (unless there was an error in the form and no action was taken). That way the same action won't be repeated if the user reloads the page.